# Layer from server as input to ArcGIS Pro Intersect

Tags: arcgis-pro, intersect, error-000840

I am working in ArcGIS Pro 2.6.1 and I have managed to pull in data from a server found here: https://spartagis.ncem.org/arcgis/rest/services. The layer in particular is the NC_AllBuildings layer. I am trying to use this layer as an input to an intersect tool but when I try to use the layer, I receive an error `ERROR 000840 The value is not a Feature Layer`. I have tried to directly download the data from the [website](https://www.nconemap.gov/datasets/NCEM-GIS::nc-building-footprints/geoservice?geometry=-80.7982%2C35.3597%2C-78.7146%2C36.5778) using a spatial subset but have not had any luck. I have even let it run overnight but when I come back in the morning it has not downloaded.

Is there a way I can use the data from the server as an input to the intersect tool that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to paste this link `https://spartagis.ncem.org/arcgis/rest/services/Public/NC_AllBuildings/MapServer/0` in the Portal search bar which allowed me to add the layer as a Feature Layer. I was then able to perform geoprocessing tasks on the layer.